# How to split and regex at specific word

Tags: javascript, regex, split

Hi guys i know its a common question but i cant figure out how to use regex to do this

I have this string

```
http://localhost:3002/website/site1=mysite.xyz&site2=mysecondsite.xyz
```

and i want to split when there is "site[1 or 2]=" so it would return me always ["mysite.xyz", "mysecondsite.xyz"]

Even in this situation

```
http://localhost:3002/website/site1=mysite.xyz&start_at=2022-07-06&end_at=2022-07-06&site2=mysecondsite.xyz&start_at2=2022-07-06&end_at2=2022-07-06
```

it must return me ["mysite.xyz", "mysecondsite.xyz"]

So for this i thought about using regex with split, did this but ofc it doesnt work  `window.location.pathname.split(/site=/);`

If regex doesnt works on 2 words dynamically like i'm looking for. I can run the split function two times like

```
window.location.pathname.split(/site1=/);
```

```
window.location.pathname.split(/site2=/);
```

but it doesnt returns me only the website elements `["mysite.xyz"]` and ["mysecondsite.xyz"]

In clear i want to do something this

```
mystring.split(get only site string after the equals and only that)
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here repeated matching is better than splitting. The match expression is:

- "site" followed by some digits
- equals sign
- capture group 1: a bunch of characters that are not `&` (this will terminate at the next parameter, or at the end of the string)

Then just extract the capture group 1.

```js
function* findSites(url) {
  const re = /site\d+=([^&]+)/g;
  let match;
  while ((match = re.exec(url))) {
    yield match[1];
  };
}


const url = "http://localhost:3002/website/site1=mysite.xyz&start_at=2022-07-06&end_at=2022-07-06&site2=mysecondsite.xyz&start_at2=2022-07-06&end_at2=2022-07-06";
const sites = [...findSites(url)];
console.log(sites);
```

As a general rule, use `split` when you are interested in content between the matches. If you want the content inside the matches, `split` is not a great choice.

Comment: Your snippet fails when i'm testing it, it says match isnt defined, i replaced match by url as it is in parameters but it only returns me "mysite.xyz" and not the second one

Comment: Oh. I may have forgotten to declare it. :P Try now?